# Tracing SWF file with debug version of Flash player

Tags: debugging, flash

Can I somehow log all AS3 finctions swf calls during runtime with debug version of Flash player?

P.S. I have no access to sources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the swf is compiled to release mode, you will not be able to see the trace calls as they are not compiled into a release build. If however you know that the swf is compiled to debug mode, there is a file that you can check that the flash player logs to. The location of the file is different depending on your OS. An extract from http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/lcds/help.html?content=build_apps_6.html

> Operating system
>   Location of log file
>
> Windows 95/98/ME/2000/XP
>
> > C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash
> >     Player\Logs
>
> Windows Vista
>
> > C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs
>
> Mac OS X
>
> > /Users/username/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/Logs/
>
> Linux
>
> > /home/username/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/

Here are two plugins for firefox which can assist you with debugging swf files:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashtracer/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashbug/

Comment: It's in release mode :( Is there a way to trace release runtime?

Comment: Trace does not get compiled into the release build, therefore it is as if there was no trace command in the code.

Comment: OK. Is there a way to see methods called during runtime?

Comment: I unfortunately do no know of a way to do this :/